# How can you margin text in a button HTML

Tags: html, css

For my website i need to create download button for my app.
But i dont know how to margin text in button.

Comment: use `padding` property in the button

Comment: do you want to add margin css into HTML Button tag?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can cover the button text with a span tag and give margin style to the span tag or you can give padding to that button text.

Answer (score 0):

use HTML and CSS code, give me the example:

**Html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn-download">Download </button>
```

**and CSS**

```
.btn-download{
   padding: 8px 15px;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #007bff;
   border-color: #007bff
}
```